# Adding multiple users to FreeNAS

Tags: unix, user-accounts, freebsd, freenas

I need to add a couple dozen user accounts for ftp access to our FreeNAS box.

Is there any way to accomplish this without manually entering each one via the GUI?

Answer (score 1):

Put a bunch of `pw`(8)'s `useradd` commands in a shell-script. Transfer that to the FreeNAS box.

Login via ssh, `su` to root and run the script.